# iAD disapearing when seguing to modal view

Tags: segue, iad, adbannerview

I have a unique viewController for landscape mode, the problem is that when I segue to the landscape view controller (modal segue) the iAD disapears and it seems to stop receiving delegate methods as well. Only when I tap the tab bar to go to another view and then back again does it show again

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification

{
    NSLog(@"orientation changed");
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView && isThisView)
    {
        //[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.backgroundImageView];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayLandscapeView" sender:self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }

    else if (deviceOrientation ==  UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
        self.bannerView.hidden = NO;
        //[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundImageView];
    }
}
```